# History of word “equity” and the path to its contemporary use

Tags: etymology

I think the Latin root “equi” means on the most basic level “the same” or “equal”, but I’d like to see references and evidence for this.

I think financial use of the word “equity” has been quite common in recent history, where it means like, holding a stake in something, I guess. As if “equi” conveys economic “value”.

Some time recently some social justice theories and discourse has started to define “equity” vs “equality”, where equality means “giving people the same” and equity means “focusing on equal outcomes” or “being fair”.

I would like textual evidence to see when and where this use of the word emerged in recent times.

Comment: Actually it comes from [aequus](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=aequus).

Comment: The justicial meanings of fairness, balance, impartiality are old and well-attested in English from the 14th c. onward.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/equity

Comment: equity is not "having a stake in something per se". It means the value in dollar terms (or other currency) **you own or control** in a mortgage or other property. If you have a loan to buy property for $250.000, and have paid off $50.000 of it, that is your equity in that  property. Also, equity shares means ordinary shares in a company. What you own of the company.

Comment: @Lambie It gets confusing because we also refer to stocks, bonds, mutual funds, etc. as "equities" -- things you can buy shares of and trade.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, equities, as you say, can be a type of financial instrument but the meaning is the same. There is also equity stake in something. But it's always the same definition. It refers to a piece of the company that can be quantified in financial statements.

Comment: Are you interested in the financial stock/share sense or the “focusing on equal outcomes” sense, because those are 2 separate questions, though the financial one is very trivial? (Also note that there are various specialised uses of equity in fields like economics, e.g. [equity of condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equity_of_condition), [health inequity](https://www.who.int/news-room/facts-in-pictures/detail/health-inequities-and-their-causes), [inequity aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequity_aversion)).